# Ошибка class Application\\Form\\Form not found Zend framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework-3

Доброго времени суток!
Начал изучать Zend Framework 3 и столкнулся с непонятной ошибкой, класс не найден:

> Class Application\Form\LoginForm not found in /var/www/html/module/Application/src/Controller.php on line 21

Контроллер:

```
<?php
/*
* файл src/Controller/IndexController.php
*/
namespace Application\Controller;
use Application\Form\LoginForm;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
//... разное

public function loginAction() // Метод login
{
    $form = new LoginForm(); // здесь ошибка вылезает

    $this->layout()->setTemplate('layout/layout_login');
    return new ViewModel(['form' => $form ]);
    }
}
```

Форма:

```
<?php
/*
* файл src/Form/LoginForm.php
*/

namespace Application\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;
class LoginForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('login-form');
    }
//Остальное удалил в поисках ошибки
}
```

Подозреваю что мелочь какая то, подскажите куда копать...

Answer (score 0):

Мдя, надо внимательней читать документацию...  https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-form/advanced/
Написано черным по англицки:

> The second catch is that you ***must not*** directly instantiate your form class, but rather get an instance of it through Zend\Form\FormElementManager:

Что примерно соответствует:

> Вторая ловушка состоит в том, что вы не должны напрямую создавать экземпляр класса формы, а должны получать экземпляр из Zend\Form\FormElementManager:

Оставлю это тут, вдруг кто еще на эти грабли наступит.

Comment: Ошибка не из-за этого. Можно и на прямую создавать, хотя через FormElementManager предпочтительней